# How to create a version of testcase in testlink using API

Tags: java, testlink

I have few testcases executed in testlink. Now I want to create a version of those testcases and update execution type. Manually I can create a version of testcase and update execution type. I have around 1000 testcases.

Is there any api available in testlink to achieve above?